# How to pass special characters in the URL when using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping, python-requests

My queryUrl variable holds this string

```
queryUrl = "https://www.coursera.org/search?query=data%20science&index=prod_all_launched_products_term_optimization_skills_test_for_precise_xdp_imprecise_variant&topic=data%20science&entityTypeDescription=Courses"
```

but when i pass it to the driver like this

self.driver.get(queryUrl)

and the browser opens, the URL has this look

https://www.coursera.org/search?query=data science&index=prod_all_launched_products_term_optimization_skills_test_for_precise_xdp_imprecise_variant&topic=data science&entityTypeDescription=Courses

The %20 special character for space becomes a white space, while i need %20 special character.

What am'i doing wrong?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem, in my computer with python 3.10 works ok. what python version are you using? are you using chrome?.

Comment: @PabloEstevez I'm using Firefox because chrome doesn't run headless for some reason. Python version 3.10.6

Answer (score 1):

using + instead of %20 should work just fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).